# Make an overlay div fill entire of a container having overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to display a loader inside the container. I am trying to display the overlay div inside the container.

if I use absolute position, the overlay also going top.

Here is Fddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/5/

Code :

```
<style>
.container
{
    margin: 25%;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    overflow:auto;
}

.overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:.8;
    text-align:center;

}

.loader {
display:inline-block;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span class="loader">
        loading...
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Here is content ... <div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: which one ? .overlay??

Comment: you are assigning fixed change to absolute...

Comment: its working, but when scroll the container, overlay also going top.

Comment: use position:absolute for the .overlay

Comment: @Arul your overlay is going up bcoz your content height is bigger than the overlay

Comment: @coder : that is my scenario

Comment: Here is your solution http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/2/

Comment: @Jake745 you didn't do anything there but change the background color. If you put some text inside `.content` and color it white, you can tell the `.overlay` is not over top of the text.

Comment: overlay will not go top! it fills the div

Comment: I removed height and width and changed the position

Comment: now improved the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/5/) and question. I think it will help to understand the requirements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I should note that a `fixed` element is positioned relative to the **[initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)** which is established for the `html` element.

Hence you should use `absolute` positioning to position the overlay relative to its nearest **[containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block)** which is established by the `container`.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.overlay { position: absolute; }
```

Second, It will work until the content start growing. When the content height gets bigger than the overlay, the overlay will not fill the entire space of the container anymore.

Since you may use JavaScript in order to to display the overlay (including loading, etc.) one solution is to add `overflow: hidden;` to the container to prevent from scrolling.

Finally, you should set `top` property of the `.overlay` element according to the position of the vertical scroll-bar.

Here is the jQuery version of the above approach:

```javascript
var $container = $(".container");

$(".overlay").fadeIn().css("top", $container.scrollTop() + "px");
$container.css("overflow", "hidden");
```

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using margin: 25%  on container which is causing the gap of 50% top-bottom value for overlay, so use height: 150% instead of 100%

```
.container
{
    margin: 25%;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    overflow:auto;
}

.overlay {
    width:100%;
    height: 150%;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    opacity:.5;
}

.content {
height:300px;
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/3/)

Comment: '.content' is just for sample, i don't know the content height. just imagine if there is some user list inside container.

Comment: Your fiddle also does not work. Scroll down inside the .container element. The .overlay scrolls up out of the top when you scroll to the bottom. What he wants is for the .overlay to be 'fixed' inside the .container even when it scrolls with the .content, which I don't think is possible in pure CSS.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike : now check the fiddle and scroll up the container.

Comment: Both Safari and Chrome on OSX there is a white gap at the bottom when you scroll down in the `.container`

Answer (score 0):

**`position: absolute`** will let you place any page element exactly where you want it with the help of `top` `right` `bottom` `left` attributes. These values will be relative to the next parent element.

**`position: fixed`** is a special case of absolute positioning. A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport.

In your case you should use `position: absolute` for your `.overlay`

Comment: now check the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/4/), then you can understand my exact requirement. when i scroll the container , overlay also going top

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container overlay">
     <div class="content"><div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    margin: 25%;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    overflow:auto;
}

.overlay {

    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
    opacity:.5;
}

.content {
height:300px;
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaykmry4/2/)

Comment: If you consider container as overlay. where will you place the loader.gif